# OData Linq to Query String

Tags: c#, linq, odata

I'm using Web API with OData Query support (nighties) and while I'm aware that the WCF library gives you the ability to query WCF RIA Service URLs what I'm looking for is a lightweight way of generating Odata Query strings sort of like LinqPad does but more generically.

For instance if we know that a service returns a specific type of say "ProductDTO", I want to be able to do something like this:

```
(from p in ODataSource<ProductDTO>
 where p.Name == "hi"
 select new {p.Model, Name}).ToODataQuery();
```

Which would return the appropriate $filter and $select commands as a string that can be appended to the URL.

Anyone know of any library that can do something like this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Another possiblity would be to use the [Simple.OData.Client](https://github.com/object/Simple.OData.Client) as outline here: [Can this library be used to generate the request url only?](https://github.com/object/Simple.OData.Client/issues/99).

Answer (score 3):

You could try this: https://github.com/ubergeoff/HollowPoint.Azure

```
ODataSource.Query()
.Where(t => t.Age >= 16 && t.Age < 33)
.ToODataString();
```

Would output the OData query text:

```
((Age ge 16) and (Age lt 33))
```

Comment: Looks like it's only for table storage.?

Answer (score 2):

I haven't used it, but am researching a similar topic, and this looks like it should provide the functionality that you're looking for:
https://bitbucket.org/jjrdk/linq2rest/wiki/Home

Here's an article that shows using it as an oData client:
http://blog.petegoo.com/index.php/2012/03/11/creating-a-net-queryable-client-for-asp-net-web-api-odata-services/

Based on the wiki (and not based on any experience with linq2rest), it appears that it goes both ways - LINQ expression to query string, and query string to LINQ expression.

Comment: This appears to go the opposite way and parses the QueryString passed into Linq. I'm looking for a javascript/jquery library that allows me to generate the $filter= and $select etc. Preferably one that works really well with Typescript interfaces so that everything is strongly typed....

Comment: Oh, I didn't see anything about javascript/jquery/typescript in the original question.